# Spring Webflux + Server-Sent Events keep Sink open for further connections

Tags: spring-webflux, reactive-programming, server-sent-events

I want to distribute messages to several clients with Spring Webflux controller and a Server-Sent-Events endpoint. I use a Sink which receives the message on another endpoint and distributes them via a Flux in the SSE endpoint. This is the simplified code of the controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/sse")
public class MessageController {

    private static final Sinks.Many<SystemMessageDto> fluxSink = Sinks.many().multicast().onBackpressureBuffer();

    @GetMapping(path = "/stream", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    public Flux<ServerSentEvent<SystemMessageDto>> getFluxMessages(@RequestParam String userName) {
        return Flux.merge(Flux.from(fluxSink.asFlux()).log()
                        .filter(m -> m.getUserName().equals(userName))
                        .map(e -> ServerSentEvent.<SystemMessageDto>builder().data(e).build()),
                Flux.interval(Duration.ofMinutes(55))       // prevent proxy from closing connection
                        .map(sequence -> ServerSentEvent.<SystemMessageDto>builder()
                                .event("keep-alive")
                                .comment("Keeping alive.")
                                .retry(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
                                .build())
        );
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/test/{userName}")
    public void testFlux(@PathVariable String userName) {
        final SystemMessageDto messageDto = SystemMessageDto.builder()
                .userName(userName)
                .message("TEST")
                .build();

        fluxSink.tryEmitNext(messageDto);
    }
}
```

This works fine for hours and several clients as long as at least one client is connected. But as soon as all clients are closed the Sink is completed and no further connections can be opened. Is there a way to keep the Sink open indefinitely or do I have to choose a completely different approach? I tried to subscribe the Sink with a dummy Flux which just logs the messages, but this didn't work either.

Here are the logs for a short test run

```
// calling /sse/stream?userName=alpha
[reactor-http-nio-3] INFO  reactor.Flux.SinkManyEmitterProcessor.1 - onSubscribe(SinkManyEmitterProcessor.EmitterInner)
[reactor-http-nio-3] INFO  reactor.Flux.SinkManyEmitterProcessor.1 - request(32)
// calling /sse/test/alpha
[reactor-http-nio-5] INFO  reactor.Flux.SinkManyEmitterProcessor.1 - onNext(SystemMessageDto(id=null, userName=alpha, message=TEST, read=false))
// calling /sse/stream?userName=beta
[reactor-http-nio-5] INFO  reactor.Flux.SinkManyEmitterProcessor.2 - onSubscribe(SinkManyEmitterProcessor.EmitterInner)
[reactor-http-nio-5] INFO  reactor.Flux.SinkManyEmitterProcessor.2 - request(32)
// calling /sse/test/beta
[reactor-http-nio-7] INFO  reactor.Flux.SinkManyEmitterProcessor.1 - onNext(SystemMessageDto(id=null, userName=beta, message=TEST, read=false))
[reactor-http-nio-7] INFO  reactor.Flux.SinkManyEmitterProcessor.1 - request(1)
[reactor-http-nio-7] INFO  reactor.Flux.SinkManyEmitterProcessor.2 - onNext(SystemMessageDto(id=null, userName=beta, message=TEST, read=false))
// close connection beta
[reactor-http-nio-5] INFO  reactor.Flux.SinkManyEmitterProcessor.2 - cancel()
// calling /sse/stream?userName=beta
[reactor-http-nio-7] INFO  reactor.Flux.SinkManyEmitterProcessor.3 - onSubscribe(SinkManyEmitterProcessor.EmitterInner)
[reactor-http-nio-7] INFO  reactor.Flux.SinkManyEmitterProcessor.3 - request(32)
// calling /sse/test/beta
[reactor-http-nio-9] INFO  reactor.Flux.SinkManyEmitterProcessor.1 - onNext(SystemMessageDto(id=null, userName=beta, message=TEST, read=false))
[reactor-http-nio-9] INFO  reactor.Flux.SinkManyEmitterProcessor.1 - request(1)
[reactor-http-nio-9] INFO  reactor.Flux.SinkManyEmitterProcessor.3 - onNext(SystemMessageDto(id=null, userName=beta, message=TEST, read=false))
// close connection alpha
[reactor-http-nio-3] INFO  reactor.Flux.SinkManyEmitterProcessor.1 - cancel()
// close connection beta
[reactor-http-nio-7] INFO  reactor.Flux.SinkManyEmitterProcessor.3 - cancel()
// calling /sse/stream?userName=alpha
[reactor-http-nio-9] INFO  reactor.Flux.SinkManyEmitterProcessor.4 - onSubscribe(SinkManyEmitterProcessor.EmitterInner)
[reactor-http-nio-9] INFO  reactor.Flux.SinkManyEmitterProcessor.4 - request(32)
[reactor-http-nio-9] INFO  reactor.Flux.SinkManyEmitterProcessor.4 - onComplete()
// all further connects to the stream result in an onComplete, calls to /sse/test/{userName} have no effect any more
```